# How to use process.StartInfo.Arguments in command prompt?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, python-2.7, command-prompt

I wanted to use my c# visual studio to open command prompt using process.StartInfo.FileName and process.StartInfo.Arguments to give commands automatically however this does not work out. Anyone knows how to do this? ( I am using the cmd to call for my python script )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following. Hope this helps. Replace notepad.exe with something else you like.

```
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c notepad.exe");
   p.Start();
```

Please refer to http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This opens notepad and a file called foo

```
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad");
        procInfo.Arguments = "foo.txt";
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procInfo;
        proc.Start(); //Actually executes the process
        proc.WaitForExit(); //Waits until the process completes, in this case, when you close notepad
```

So for your thing you would call the python interpreter and pass the python script as arguments, along with anything else the interpreter needs (I have 0.1% knowledge of python)

Important note: Make sure your executable is in the path.